# Exception handling in RX.Net when using ToEventPattern and Timeout

Tags: c#, rx.net

I am writing some code using RX in C# that must interface with an older system by emitting events.

In summary, I have an observable and need to emit one event when the observable completes and another event if a timeout exception is detected. The main problem is how best to handle the exception.

I'm relatively new to RX, so although I have found a solution, I can't be sure that there isn't a better or more appropriate way that uses the RX extensions better.

This is not the real code but indicates the pattern of my thinking:

```
    public delegate void SuccessHandler(object sender, SuccessEventArgs e);
    public event SuccessHandler OnSuccess;

    public delegate void TimeoutHandler(object sender, TimeoutEventArgs e);
    public event TimeoutHandler OnTimeout;

    var id;
    var o = Observable.Return()     // <- this would be a fetch from an asynchronous source
        .Where(r=>r.status=="OK")
        .Timeout(new Timespan(0,0,30)
        .Do(r=> {
             id=r.Id           // <-- Ugh! I know this shouldn't be done!
         }
        .Subscribe(r => {

             var statusResponse= new StatusResponse()
             {
               Id = r.Id
               Name = r.Name
                  Message = "The operation completed successfully",
                  Status = Status.Success
             };

             if (OnSuccess == null) return;
                OnSuccess (this, new SuccessEventArgs(statusResponse);
           },
           e =>
           {
             _logger.LogError(e, "A matching response was not returned in a timely fashion");

             if (OnTimeout == null) return;
             OnTimeout(this, new TimeoutEventArgs(id));
           });
```

If I didn't need to detect and act upon the timeout it would be fine; I have already worked out how to substitute the Subscribe for ToEventPattern:

```
         ...
    .Select(r =>
    {
         var statusResponse= new StatusResponse()
         {
           Id = r.Id
           Name = r.Name
           Message = "The operation completed successfully",
           Status = Status.Success
         };
         return new EventPattern<SuccessEventArgs>(this, new SuccessEventArgs(statusResponse));
    })
    .ToEventPattern();
```

However, I'd like to be able to detect the timeout (and possibly other exceptions). my experiments with Catch have been unsuccessful because I can't seem to get the types to line up correctly, probably because I don't really understand what is going on.

I'd very much appreciate opinions on this. Is this an acceptable solution? How can I improve it? Can anyone point me to some good online references that will explain how this kind of flow-control and exception handling can be done (all the examples I've seen so far seem to stop short of the real-world case where you  want to emit an event *and* combine that with exception handling).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can branch from observables quite easily, e.g.

```
var a = Observable.Range(0, 10);
var b = a.Select(x => x * x);
var c = a.Select(x => x * 10);
```

A word of warning - if the observable is *cold*, this will cause the producer function to run for each subscription. Look up the difference between *hot* and *cold* observables if this isn't clear.

I've created a solution that creates two branches from the source observable and turns each into an event:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        var service = new Service();
        var apiCall = service.CallApi();
        apiCall.OnSuccess.OnNext += (_, __) => Console.WriteLine("Success!");
        apiCall.OnTimeout.OnNext += (_, __) => Console.WriteLine("Timeout!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
class SuccessEventArgs{}
class TimeoutEventArgs{}

class ApiCall
{
    public IEventPatternSource<SuccessEventArgs> OnSuccess {get;}

    public IEventPatternSource<TimeoutEventArgs> OnTimeout {get;}

    public ApiCall(IEventPatternSource<SuccessEventArgs> onSuccess, IEventPatternSource<TimeoutEventArgs> onTimeout)
    {
        OnSuccess = onSuccess;
        OnTimeout = onTimeout;
    }
}
class Service
{
    public ApiCall CallApi()
    {    
        var apiCall = Observable
            .Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
            .Do(_ => Console.WriteLine("Api Called"))
            .Select(_ => new EventPattern<SuccessEventArgs>(null, new SuccessEventArgs()))
            // .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)) // uncomment to time out
            .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4))
            // the following two lines turn the "cold" observable "hot"
            // comment them out and see how often "Api Called" is logged
            .Publish()
            .RefCount();

        var success = apiCall
            // ignore the TimeoutException and return an empty observable
            .Catch<EventPattern<SuccessEventArgs>, TimeoutException>(_ => Observable.Empty<EventPattern<SuccessEventArgs>>())
            .ToEventPattern();

        var timeout = apiCall
            .Materialize() // turn the exception into a call to OnNext rather than OnError
            .Where(x => x.Exception is TimeoutException)
            .Select(_ => new EventPattern<TimeoutEventArgs>(null, new TimeoutEventArgs()))
            .ToEventPattern();

        return new ApiCall(success, timeout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi  NickL, Sorry for the delay in replying to this. This looks like the kind of guidance I  was looking for. After a bit of a break I will soon be returning to this work and will apply these ideas.